# python get instance.list[0][0] by typing instance(0, 0)

Tags: python

hi i have a class Grid with an instance grid and i would like for `grid(0, 0)` to return `grid.content[0][0]` with content being a list containing lists

```
class Grid():
  def __init__(self):
    self.content = [[" " for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

grid = Grid()
print(grid(5, 4)) # out => grid.content[5][4]
```

Comment: Consider using `[]` and `__getitem__` instead of `()` and `__call__` though. Square braces are what's used for indexing in Python, so that will likely make more sense to people writing your code. You can use `__getitem__` to allow for `grid[5, 4]` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `__call__` method in the class:

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = [[f"{i}/{j}" for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return self.content[x][y]


grid = Grid()
print(grid(5, 4))  # out => grid.content[5][4] i.e. '4/5'
```